# Charge 2017 13" Macbook air through Thunderbolt 2 port, while connecting display

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, thunderbolt-display

I currently have a 2017, 13" Macbook Air, and have been looking to buy a monitor to have at home. Is there a product that would allow me to power my computer, while connecting an external monitor (preferably HDMI), through the Thunderbolt 2 port?

Comment: Thunderbolt 2 does not support power delivery. Is that your question?

Comment: Yep that makes sense. I was just hoping there would be a nice simple solution but alas

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately not. As stated in the comment, TB2 does not support power delivery.
If you were to find an old [Apple 27" Thunderbolt Display](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP642) it comes with a cable that has both a TB2 connector and a Magsafe 2 connector, which can both deliver display signal from the laptop to the monitor AND power from the monitor to the laptop.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Thunderbolt_Display
I don't think there's a 3:rd party monitor that has that available unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your reply, It’s so upsetting that the Thunderbolt 2 port has been so thoroughly replaced with the USB-C port.